# Print log error and save it to a file

Tags: file, go, logging

I have created a simple custom logger to print the error log and save it to a file with specific location.

```
package logger

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

var trace *log.Logger
var filePathVar string
var fileNameVar string
var prefixVar string

// use this function first before calling others.
func InitLogger(prefix, filePath, fileName string) {
    setPrefix(prefix)
    createLogFile(prefix, filePath, fileName)
    filePathVar = filePath
    fileNameVar = fileName
    prefixVar = prefix
}

func setPrefix(prefix string) {
    trace = log.New(os.Stderr,
        prefix,
        log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)

}

func createLogFile(prefix, filePath, fileName string) (*os.File, error) {
    setPrefix(prefix)
    f, err := os.OpenFile(filePath+fileName, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, os.ModePerm)
    if err != nil {
        // error file is not created
        err = os.MkdirAll(filePath, os.ModePerm)
        if err != nil {
            trace.Println(err)
            return nil, err
        }
        createLogFile(prefix, filePath, fileName)
    }

    return f, nil
}

// use this PrintLog use print the error on the terminal without exitting apps.
func PrintLog(errorLog string) {
    //assign to global variable
    if filePathVar == "" || fileNameVar == "" || prefixVar == "" {
        trace.Fatalln("Error file path and Name empty prefix Cannot be Empty")
    }

    f, err := createLogFile(prefixVar, filePathVar, fileNameVar)
    if err != nil {
        trace.Fatalln(err)
        return
    }
    trace.Println(errorLog)
    // save the log out put to file
    trace.SetOutput(f)
    trace.Println(errorLog, err)
}

// use this Fatal log to exit the application whenever got error.
func FatalLog(errorLog string) {
    //assign to global variable
    if filePathVar == "" || fileNameVar == "" || prefixVar == "" {
        trace.Fatalln("Error file path and Name empty")
    }

    f, err := createLogFile(prefixVar, filePathVar, fileNameVar)
    if err != nil {
        trace.Fatalln(err)
        return
    }
    trace.Println(errorLog)
    // save the log out put to file
    trace.SetOutput(f)
    trace.Fatalln(errorLog, err)
}
```

To use this package I must call the `InitLogger` function first

```
logger.InitLogger("Prefix Logger","./filpath/","filename.txt")
```

And then after that I can choose to print the error using either `PrintLog` or `FatalLog`.

The `PrintLog` function is used when we wanted to print the log without having crashing or closing the app `os.Exit`. The `FatalLog` the same as `PrintLog` but will crash the app or call `os.Exit`.

Any idea what can be improved here? [source code](https://github.com/Gujarats/API-Golang/tree/12988a5f16146154adcc3b6ea8f97d34411abee6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If some of your init values (prefix, filePath, fileName) are empty, you should fail on init, not once you try to log something. Returning errors as soon as possible is a good practice and makes debugging much easier.
- `setPrefix` should be called `setCustomLogger` or something, or better, since it's a one-line function, just inline it.
- You're calling `setPrefix` twice on init. `createLogFile` shouldn't call it.
- Don't join paths using string concatenation. Use `filepath.Join` instead.
- You should check that `createLogFile` succeeds on init, and fail fast otherwise.
- `InitLogger` should simply be called `Init`, `PrintLog` should be `Print`, `FatalLog` should be `Fatal`: you're going to call them with `logger.[…]` from outside your package.
- godoc comments should start with the name of the function they document: `PrintLog prints a log message on the console, as well as in the log file…` or something.
- Why are you calling `createLogFile` many times? Just call it on init, save the file somewhere and use it each time. I think this also allows you to get rid of all these weird variables and replace them with only what you need (an open file).
- Hoooo I understand why, it's because it needs to be reinitialized to `os.Stderr`. Damn, that's complex. Why not simply have two loggers (once initialized to `os.Stderr` and the other to your file, and simply call the corresponding function on each when your custom logger is called?
- You're never closing your file. There is no way you can do that from your logging package (unless you open/close it every time you write a log line, but this is terribly inefficient), so maybe your `Init` function should take a `os.File` argument instead of a file path + file name. This way, the `main` function of your program (which will initialize the logger) can close it once the program is over. Of course, you should also close it when `Fatal` is called

In short: your `Print` method should be two lines long, your `Fatal` method should be three lines long, you shouldn't have more than 2 global variables, and all errors should be caught on `Init`.